# How to find the closest coordinate inside Python dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of names and coordinates (lat, long) and I want to to find using haversine distance the closest coordinates to another....

I have tried to use a loop to calculate the haversine distance for each coordinate to every other in the dataframe but I find this method is very slow

```py
Names, Coord
ab     (51.44, 0.224)
ad     (-58.256, 0.224)
af     (53.44, 0.232)
ag     (51.67, 0.123)
ay     (50.44, 1.718)
as     (59.93, -1.582)
al     (53.40, 0.224)
```

Given this input dataframe, for each name and Coord using haversine distance find a name of a point that is within 250 meters...create a column Closest and note the name and Nan if no point is within 250 meters

```py
Names, Coord, Closest
ab     (51.44, 0.224)   ad
ad     (-58.256, 0.224) ab
af     (53.44, 0.232)   ay
ag     (51.67, 0.123)   al
ay     (50.44, 1.718)   af
as     (59.93, -1.582)  Nan
al     (53.40, 0.224)   ag
```

Comment: How many loop did you use can you share your code ?

Comment: I do not think there is a point close within 250 metres. Or do you mean Kilometres?? ie to find the haversine distance you could do: `import numpy as np;from haversine import haversine;np.vectorize(haversine)(df.Coord,df.Coord.values[:,None],'m')`

Comment: for example, you do have that `ab` is close to `ad`, but doing the ``haversine distance, we obtain: `haversine(df.Coord[0],df.Coord[1],'m')
Out[135]: 12197655.521297626`. This is way out of the 250 metres gap. Just check the gap. you have  a point ad on the north hemisphere while you have ad on the southern hemisphere. There is no way the two points can be close!!!